# How do you create a Magento 2 Admin Theme as a repository in vendor DIR?

Tags: github, repository, admin, magento-2.3

I've created a repository in GitHub for my admin theme thinking i could update it through packagist.   when i do update the theme it shows in my vendor directory which is perfect but doesn't work

I see the admin files for my version as en_US compiled in the pub/static directory, even the logo i setup shows if you go direct to the pub version in the browser but the website just wont use it

my registration.php file in the root of the repo is as follows

```
<?php use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;
ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
'adminhtml/Bigboppa/backend', __DIR__);
```

I was expecting to see my logo for example in the admin login screen, if I just got that far i'd know I was on the right track.

right now I'm stumped!!!